# Show that a group with $xa=ax^{-1}$, for all $x\in G$, where $a$ is fixed in $G$, is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Fix $a$ in a group $G$. How can I prove that $G$ is abelian if for every $x\in G$
$$
xa=ax^{-1}?$$
I am thinking that it is enough to show that $x^2=e$, where $e\in G$ is the identity element. I started with
$$
x^2=(ax^{-1}a^{-1})^2=ax^{-1}a^{-1}ax^{-1}a^{-1}=ax^{-2}a^{-1}.
$$
But from here I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You can deduce that identity even more simply, starting from $x^2a=ax^{-2}$.

Comment: Generalization: if in a group $G$ $j:x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is a group homomorphism, then $G$ is abelian. Here we have the assumption that $j$ is an inner automorphism. Possibly the generalization is an even easier exercise!

Answer (score 9):

*Hint:* Take $x=a$. Then take $x=ya$.

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$\begin{align} 
(xy)a &= a(xy)^{-1} \\
&= ay^{-1}x^{-1} \\
&= yax^{-1}\\
&= yxa.
\end{align}$$
Now cancel the $a$.

Comment: Very nice direct proof.